# I don't know why I keep having Accessing PropTypes in React is deprecated even if I used 'prop-types' package?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I think I am doing propType checking in this component properly, this is the code that passes props:

```
<TodoTextInput
   autoFocus={true}
   className="new-todo"
   onSave={this._handleTextInputSave}
   placeholder="What needs to be done?"
/>
```

and my only component that checks for proptypes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class TodoTextInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
  };
  _addTodo = () => { // To add remove and edit functionality 
    const trimText = this.state.text.trim();
     if (trimText !== '') { 
      this.props.onSave(trimText); 
      this.setState({text: ''}); 
    }
  };
  _handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._addTodo}> {
        <input type="text"
          onChange={this._handleChange}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

TodoTextInput.propTypes = {
  onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};
```

obviously onSave is func and placeholder is a string but why do I still have this error? I removed the PropTypes checking but still have it. why?

> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated.
>   Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

Comment: It can happen you you are using packages that still use prop-types from the React npm package, hence two things you can do, 1. Delete node_modules and then install the latest packages, or since some other package may not have updated with the current version, for now you can reduce your react version to < 15.5.0

Comment: Like @ShubhamKhatri said, upgrading your react package may solve this issue. The [latest version of react](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.5.4) (as of this writing) indicates a **Critical Bugfix** to the prop-types package.